# Send int over socket in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winsock, qnx-neutrino

I have troubles with sending an array of ints over a socket.
the code looks like this

Program 1: (running on windows)

```cpp
int bmp_info_buff[3];

/* connecting and others */

/* Send informations about bitmap */
send(my_socket, (char*)bmp_info_buff, 3, 0);
```

Program 2: (running on neutrino)

```
/*buff to store bitmap information size, with, length */
int bmp_info_buff[3];

/* stuff */

/* Read informations about bitmap */
recv(my_connection, bmp_info_buff, 3, NULL);
printf("Size of bitmap: %d\nwidth: %d\nheight: %d\n", bmp_info_buff[0], bmp_info_buff[1], bmp_info_buff[2]);
```

It should print
Size of bitmap: 64
width: 8
height: 8

Size of bitmap: 64
width: 6
height: 4096
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you send the `bmp_info_buff` array as char array, the size of `bmp_info_buff`  is not 3 but is `3 * sizeof(int)`

The same for `recv`

Replace

```
send(my_socket, (char*)bmp_info_buff, 3, 0);
recv(my_connection, bmp_info_buff, 3, NULL);
```

by

```
send(my_socket, (char*)bmp_info_buff, 3*sizeof(int), 0);
recv(my_connection, bmp_info_buff, 3*sizeof(int), NULL);
```

Comment: But what about byte ordering issues?  Writing ints from a big-endian machine to a little-endian machine requires usage of `htonl`, `ntohl`, etc.

Comment: In addition, make sure you check the return values from `send` and `recv`. They're the only way to be sure what really happened.

Answer (score 8):

The size argument to `send()` and `recv()` is in bytes, not `int`s. You're sending/receiving too little data.

You need:

```
send(my_socket, bmp_info_buff, sizeof bmp_info_buff, 0);
```

and

```
recv(my_connection, bmp_info_buff, sizeof bmp_info_buff, 0);
```

Also note:

- This makes your code sensitive to byte endianness issues.
- The size of `int` is not the same on all platforms, you need to consider this, too.
- No need to cast the pointer argument, it's `void *`.
- You should also add code to check the return values, I/O can fail!
- The last argument to `recv()` shouldn't be `NULL` as in your code, it's a flags integer just as in `send()`.

Comment: +1. But don't people know about the `sizeof` keyword or what?

Comment: Also, there is an issue about possible 32/64bit mismatch to add.